# Delete all files from folder older than a specified amount of time with custom function

Tags: php

I am trying to delete all files from a folder that are older than x hours (current example is for one hour). But it doesn't respect the condition, the script delete all the files from the folder, doesn't matter if they are older than 1 hour or newer than 1 hour.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL); 
  ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

  function destroy($dir) {
    $mydir = opendir($dir);
    while($file = readdir($mydir)) {
      if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
        if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
          chdir('.');
          while($dir.$file) {
            if(date("U",filectime($file)) >= time() - 3600) {
                unlink($dir.$file);
        echo $file.' had been deleted';
            }
          }
        } else
          unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
      }
    }
    closedir($mydir);
  }

  $docroot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  $docroot = $docroot.'/scrapers/thumbnails/';
  destroy($docroot);
?>
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but if you are getting the age of the file in seconds since 1 Jan 1970, an older file (relative to today) will have an age that is a smaller number of seconds (since it will be nearer 1970), not larger.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I see.Hmm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
function destroy($dir) {
    $mydir = opendir($dir);
    while($file = readdir($mydir)) {
        if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
            if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
                chdir('.');
                while($dir.$file) {
                    if((time() -  filemtime($file)) > 3600) {
                        unlink($dir.$file);
                        echo $file.' had been deleted';
                    }
                }
            } else
                if((time() -  filemtime($file)) > 3600) {
                    unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file<br />");
                }
        }
    }
    closedir($mydir);
}
```

Comment: Still deletes the new files (all files), newer than 1 hour, and also echo's `Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for 1395644972173331.png in`

Comment: this is maybe then a problem with the realpath of the file. What is in your `$dir`? Try `filemtime($dir . '/' . $file)`